# How can I download (or compile) the libraries "stdlib.lib" and "stdlib.a"? (To use them for assembly)

Tags: assembly, libraries, masm, masm32

I have the following code:

```
include stdlib.a
includelib stdlib.lib
```

But on assembling, it gives me an error: "*cannot open file : stdlib.a*"

I haven't any file called "stdlib.lib" or "stdlib.a".

I've been searching for those files, but I can't find them. The only file I can find is "stdlib.h"(look Ramhound's answer), but WinAsm doesn't recognise it on compiling.

Is there any way to transform the "stdlib.h" to "stdlib.lib" or "stdlib.a", or to use in assembly? ( **From Ramhound's answer** : * "stdlib.h" is a header, not a library. It can't be converted to "stdlib.lib" or "stdlib.a" *).

Thanks!!!

**EDIT 1**
In Ramhound's answer, he explains that *stdlib.h* is a "header", not a library. Could someone help me with the *stdlib.lib* and *stdlib.a* ?

I've been looking for those files, but I can't find them. I would appreciate some help with those libraries. (Why every one have them but I can't find where to download them?

Comment: stdlib.h is a header file it doens't contain any of the standard library code.  Header files cannot be converted to .lib files.  I suggest you do more research on how C/C++ programming works its not clear which your using in a case like this.

Comment: Thanks. I've researched on C and C++, but I can't find them. I'll keep looking for the libraries.

Comment: Its not clear what compiler your using.  There is a difference if your running this software on Windows or Unix/Linux.

Comment: OS: Windows 7

Assembler: WinAsam

Answer (score 0):

WinASM is an IDE not an Assembler.  Both `include` and `includelib` are MASM.  If you want to use C functions, you need to link against Microsofts C Runtime - MSVCRT.dll.  MASM32 contains the `inc` and import library:

```
include msvcrt.inc
includelib msvcrt.lib
```

The MASM32 import library prepends `crt_` to the function names, so `wscanf` would be called `crt_wscanf`

Comment: Perhaps coincidence, but both `stdlib.lib` (for Windows) and `stdlib.a` (for Linux) are part of the HLA package. I suspect that may be what you need.